# Retrieving form to create issue in JIRA Rest Java Client

Tags: java, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to create a program that would display mandatory fields for a particular issue type for a project. So far I am able to display values for projects and issues using the JRJC. However I am not able to figure out how to display a default screen. Anybody face the same issue ?

Thanks

Comment: I guess its something to with getCreateMetaData but still cannot figure out how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats right - you need to call the createmeta call with the project key, the issue type key and then expand the fields -

```
curl -D- -u fred:fred -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta?projectKeys=QA&issuetypeNames=Bug&expand=projects.issuetypes.fields
```

This will give you a list of fields and you can check if this field is required or not.

The JRJC equivalent is the getCreateMetaData  call

```
GetCreateIssueMetadataOptions  options = new GetCreateIssueMetadataOptionsBuilder()
        .withExpandedIssueTypesFields()

        .withProjectKeys("CGIM")
        .build();
         List myList=(List) restClient.getIssueClient().getCreateIssueMetadata(options, pm); // getting the issue creation metadata relatively to the project im searching for
        java.util.Iterator<CimProject> it1=myList.iterator();
        while(it1.hasNext())
        {
                CimProject c=it1.next();
                List issueT=(List) c.getIssueTypes(); // getting the list of issue types linked to this project
                java.util.Iterator<CimIssueType> it2=issueT.iterator();
                while (it2.hasNext())
                {
                    CimIssueType issueType=it2.next();
                    System.out.print(issueType.getName());
                    Map<String, CimFieldInfo> fieldList=issueType.getFields(); // getting the list of fields linked to each issue type
                    for(Entry<String, CimFieldInfo> entry : fieldList.entrySet()) {
                        String cle = entry.getKey();
                        CimFieldInfo valeur = entry.getValue();
                        System.out.println(valeur.getName());
                    }
                }


        }
```